# React component creating extra div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on converting some page elements into React components and I'm encountering a strange and difficult issue.  I create the components normally like so:

```
const ComponentName = () => {
  return (
    <div className='styling-classes'>
      <SubComponentName />
    </div>
  )
}
```

and the component renders, but the problem is that React is wrapping it in an extra div that is breaking styling like so:

```html
<div id='div-containing-component'>
  <!-- React sticks this in here -->
  <div id="ComponentName-react-component-a0838426-9f52-48be-99fd-d36745dceb35">
    <div className='styling-classes'>
      <!-- more component markup -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm sure that there are good reasons for the library doing this, but rest assured, this is something that I DO NOT WANT.  I don't care what the React teams reason is for this extra div, I'm working on a legacy app with enough CSS to fill an encyclopedia and this additional div is breaking styling in a way that simply isn't fixable.  If I'm not able to eliminate it on my own I'll write a separate script to delete the extra div manually and relocate the enclosed markup but I'd prefer to not have to do all of that.  Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this div that I didn't ask for and need to go away?

Edit: After looking more deeply it appears that this is something having to do with the "React on Rails" gem that I'm using (this is an RoR project) but I don't see the reason for or how to get rid of it.

Comment: Doesn't look like that markup matches the React code snippet. Also what's the contents of SubComponentName?

Comment: @ChrisOram You're correct about the markup, I've edited it to correct.  As far as the sub-component, it's another React component containing an image.  It doesn't affect the output if it's removed, I just put it there for illustration.

Comment: Never seen React add a div in this way. What is your project setup and where are you running this? Tried to reproduce here but to no avail https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-flower-rh3zid?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is there a function wrapping the ComponentName function on the export?

Comment: @ChrisOram It's a Ruby on Rails application using the React on Rails library.  It's an extremely complex application and I don't know much about how it was initially setup.

Comment: @JonathonNordquist in that case I'm going to gracefully bow out... Don't have experience with this. Just know that React itself doesn't do this.

Comment: @CrashCodes It's just a default export but I don't really understand what you mean by "a function wrapping the ComponentName function on the export."

Comment: My best guess would be that you need to build your app in production. This could be a result of dev mode for react

Comment: @JonathonNordquist seems you have your answer already, but I was referring to Higher Order Components: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html which I thought you may have been using by convention with some other library/framework rather than pure intention. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've managed to figure out what is going on and come up with a work around.  Something I didn't know about the React on Rails library is that whenever a component is instantiated (something done in the view using a call to a `#react_component` method,) the gem creates what it calls a "wrapper" div which the actual component markup gets dropped into.

The solution is to remove the `<div className='styling-classes'>` from the component, and instead add the styling classes directly to the method call as an argument like so:

```
react_component('ComponentName', props: { key: val }, html_options: {class: 'styling-classes'})
```

It's not a perfect solution, and it breaks some of the encapsulation I'm going for with components but it works.  Hope that this can help someone else some day.  Thanks to all who lent their time and attention.

Answer (score -1):

This is specific to your rails application, can't help without more context.